# How to get dag status like running or success or failure

Tags: python-2.7, airflow

I want to know the status of dag whether it is running or failure or success. I am triggering dag through CL argument airflow trigger  and after the execution of job, I want to know the status of the run. I couldn't find any way.

I tried airflow dag_state   but it is giving none. What should I do if there are more than one runs in a day to get status of latest run through command line argument or through python code.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [list_dag_runs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/cli-and-env-variables-ref.html#list_repeat2) command with the CLI to list the dag runs for a given dag ID. The information returned includes the state of each run.

You can also retrieve the information via python code a few different ways. One such way that I've used in the past is the ['find' method in airflow.models.dagrun.DagRun](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/_api/airflow/models/dagrun/index.html#airflow.models.dagrun.DagRun.find)

An example with python3 on how to get the state of dag_runs via DagRun.find():

```
dag_id = 'fake_dag_id'
dag_runs = DagRun.find(dag_id=dag_id)
for dag_run in dag_runs:
      print(dag_run.state)
```

Comment: I tried using find method. I got output like this 

`[<DagRun Dag_for_testing_airflow_part_of_Jenkins @ 2019-11-07 05:26:19+00:00: manual__2019-11-07T05:26:19+00:00, externally triggered: True>, <DagRun Dag_for_testing_airflow_part_of_Jenkins @ 2019-11-07 05:41:35+00:00: manual__2019-11-07T05:41:35+00:00, externally triggered: True>]`

Where is dag status in this list?

Comment: It returns a list of DagRun objects. The objects have an attribute `state` you can access. I have just updated my answer with an example for python3!

Comment: It gives all the status till now. What if we only want current status ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following CL

```
airflow dag_state dag_id execution_date
```

Example:

```
        airflow dag_state test_dag_id 2019-11-08T18:36:39.628099+00:00
```

In the above example:

```
test_dag_id is the actual dag
2019-11-08T18:36:39.628099+00:00 is the execution date. You can get this from airflow UI for your run.
```

Other option is to use airflow rest api plugin. This is better option. You can trigger a DAG and also check the status of the dag.

https://github.com/teamclairvoyant/airflow-rest-api-plugin

Comment: For Airflow>=2.0, use `airflow dags state dag_id execution_date`. Also it's a shame that you cannot pass any run_id to look for a particular DagRun.